# Нарисовать фигуру (пятиугольник) и потом трансформирвать ее, перенося координаты пяти точек

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно интересует как это сделать в WPF? И еще что б трансформация была плавной, то бишь надо еще и анимировать трансформацию.

Comment: Что вы пробовали, что у вас не получается?

Comment: Думаю, вставить кусочек кода, где вы пробовали - будет эффективнее )

Comment: У меня Есть полигон, с точками, и знаю что это делается с помощю `PointAnimation` но как это сделать не знаю. Это все что у меня есть на данный момент...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx), с его помощью очень удобно рисовать разные геометрические фигуры.

Допустим вам необходимо нарисовать кнопку в форме треугольника, в таком случае Вам нужно использовать в шаблоне Path такого вида:

```
<Path Fill="DarkKhaki" Data="M10,10 L10,250 L150,120z"/>
```

**M** - означает с какого пикселя по оси X и Y мы начнём рисовать.
**L** - означает, что от начального пикселя (**M**) будет проведена линия, в нашем случае вертикальная, до 250 пикселя по оси Y. Затем снова линия проводится в указанную точку. А буква **z** означает то, что наша фигура автоматически замыкается. В итоге получим такое изображение:
[image: изображение].

На счёт анимации помочь к сожалению не смогу.